# How to incorporate an integral within a function?

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, numerical-integration

I am trying to code this gamma distribution in Python; however, I am having difficulty understanding how to incorporate the integral within the function.

Distribution:

[image: gamma.cdf]

Would the first half of the equation before the integral be defined as a separate function and then multiplied to the function that is defined by the integral?

For more context, “t” is my time variable, which is constituted of my x-data points that range from 0 - 24.

This is my attempt at writing this:

```py
#Define Gamma Function
def func(t,g,n):
    y = (1/gamma(g)*n*g)
    return y

def func1(t,g,s,n,d):
    y1 = (s**(g-1))*(np.exp(1)**(-s/n))*d*s
    return y1

I = integrate.quad(func1,0,t)

funcdata = func(xdata,2,1)*func1(xdata,1,1,1,1)
plt.plot(xdata,funcdata,label="Model")
```

Comment: The gamma distribution is implemented by scipy: [scipy.stats.gamma](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html). It seems that you are trying to implement a formula for the CDF, which one of the methods provided by scipy.

Comment: The Gamma function does not depend on the integration variable s from your picture/formula so yes, you can calculate the integral independently and just multiply the results. Also you can just write `np.exp(-s/n)` and please take a look on integral notation basics because the ds in the end of the integral does not mean that you have to multiply by some variable `d`and `s`. Also as bb1 said you should not reinvent the wheel and just use `spicy.stats.gamma` which provides `gamma.cdf` which suits your needs.